# Import excel file located on a UNIX server to SAS

Tags: excel, dataset, sas

I am trying to import a excel file to a dataset using SAS, however the regular approach:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= test.test
            DATAFILE= "M:/excelfile.xls"
            DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
     SHEET="Sheet1";
     GETNAMES=YES;
     MIXED=NO;
     SCANTEXT=YES;
     USEDATE=YES;
     SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;
```

only works on Windows.

Im using SAS 9.2 .. I tried different DBMS like XLS, EXCELCS with no luck...
I've been investing a lot of time on this I wanted to know if is possible..
I don't have access to any other languages other than SAS ans SHELL (no PERL)

Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm looking for?

These are the installed base products

Operating System:   AIX 64   
---Base Product  
 ---SAS/STAT               
---SAS/GRAPH            
---SAS/ETS 
                                           ---SAS/OR                                            ---SAS/CONNECT
---SAS Integration Technologies
---OR OPT
---OR PRS
---OR IVS
---OR LSO
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is late but for the record you should be able to import an xlsx (XML Excel data sheet) with SAS using the XML data engine and a custom XMLMAP which is provided by SAS support.

See the paper here http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/115-31.pdf for details of how to do this and where to get the XMLmap from.

Comment: hello DaveG thank you! yeah I was aware of that however I read a xls file that gets dumped into a sahed folder, anyways I ended up using perl to read the file and converting it to xml or text

Answer (score 1):

If the list of installed base products on AIX is correct, you do not have the SAS Access to PC File Formats product licensed on UNIX.  Since you mention "remote submit" and that you have SAS Access on your PC, you can transfer the file down to your PC, use PROC IMPORT, then transfer the SAS dataset back to the server:

```
rsubmit;
proc download infile='M:/excelfile.xls'
              outfile='c:\temp\excelfile.xls'
              binary;
run;
endrsubmit;

PROC IMPORT OUT=work.test
            DATAFILE= 'c:\temp\excelfile.xls'
            DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
    SHEET="Sheet1";
    GETNAMES=YES;
    MIXED=NO;
    SCANTEXT=YES;
    USEDATE=YES;
    SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;

rsubmit;
proc upload data=test out=test.test;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Hope this helps,
Bob

Comment: Thank you Bob, I thought --SAS/ACCESS Interface to DB2 mean that I had it, what you suggest is basically what I do now,  but in order to automate some of our scripts we need it done only on the UNIX side

Comment: No, DB2 refers to the IBM database product by that name.  If you are talking about automation, it might be better for you to use delimited files (tab, comma, or something else) rather than Excel workbooks.  Then you can use PROC IMPORT with DBMS=DLM.  Use care when placing text files on UNIX file systems from Windows; be sure to transfer as "text", not "binary".

Comment: ok, then i guess i dont have it, the thing is that this excel file is dumped by a vendor, and there is nothing I can do without bothering the management, I found a work around though, I made a PERL script that converts the XLS to CSV then use proc import as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://support.sas.com/onlinedoc/913/getDoc/en/proc.hlp/a000312413.htm) - the options you can use seem to be dependent on the DBMS you specify (e.g. it looks like you cannot use GETNAMES with EXCELCS). Have you tried stripping the PROC IMPORT back, i.e. by dropping some options:

```
proc import out=work.test
  datafile = "/path/to/file.xls"
  dbms = EXCELCS replace;
  sheet = "Sheet1";
run;
```

Comment: the only ouput that I receive is DMBS no supported.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate license (SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC files)? You can run PROC SETINIT;RUN; to tell you and the log should contain the line "SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files".

Comment: yes i have it, those interfaces work fine on windows, the excel file is on unix, and the proc import is executed within rsubmit on a unix server

Comment: Perhaps the module is not installed on the unix server. Maybe you could rsubmit PROC SETINIT;RUN; to see if it's installed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may just be that you need to run SAS with the `-noterminal` option, as explained [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/alrg.html).